# Shopify Cart API does not return 422 when you exceed product inventory

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-api

According to the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#error-responses), you are supposed to get a 422 response when you try to add more products to your cart than are available in stock. My problem is that I get a 200 response no matter how many items I add.

These people had the same problem:

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/AJAX-POST-cart-add-js-NEVER-returns-422-only-200-OK-on/td-p/375736

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/AJAX-API-Only-sends-error-with-jQuery/td-p/341248

The gist of their solution is to add the following to the headers, which is apparently only added by default with jQuery:

`X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`

I have also tried it with jQuery to no success, and adding the headers with Axios also has not worked (I verified that it was definitely being included):

```
updateProduct = async (update) => {
    this.setState({ processing: true }, async () => {
        const { data, status } = await axios.post(
            '/cart/update.js',
            update,
            {
                headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
            },
        );

        console.log('data = ', data);
        console.log('status = ', status);
        
        if (status === 200) {
            this.setState({ data, processing: false });
        }
    });
};
```

My understanding is that there have been some updates over the past couple years to prevent bots from abusing inventory data, but how am I supposed to make sure my custom cart does not allow you to add more items than are available if I'm unable to receive any kind of error response?

Am I doing this wrong or is there some Shopify setting I need to change?

Comment: In my case it always works, you need to check and make sure all conditions are like inventory setup and multiple location inventory are set up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed this: [image]

Using `/cart/add.js` instead of `/cart/update.js` fixes the problem.